# Atom editor: disable anti-aliasing

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts, text-editors, anti-aliasing, atom-editor

I have been using Sublime Text 2 for a while and are trying to switch to GitHub's Atom editor. Probably the only issue I still haven't resolved is font rendering. The text in the Atom editor is *very* blurry.

Everywhere else (including Chrome), the text is sharp and OK to read. But not for Atom. For comparison: text rendering for Atom (first line) and Sublime Text 2 (second line).

[image]

Both editors use the Monokai theme, with the same font (Consolas, size 12) and font color.

My OS is Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and I have ClearType disabled. I am using the latest version of Atom, which is currently 1.0.11.

I have already done an extensive search and found a lot of solutions, but none of them worked. For example: [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-font-weight-anti-alias/4212), [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/text-rendering-seems-blurry-compared-to-other-editors/13927), [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7261), and [this](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1650).

---

**UPDATE**

I have made some progress on the topic. If I disable DirectWrite, then the text becomes more sharp, but other images and graphics become more jaggy. But since I look at the text 99% of the time, this is not an issue.

My solution to disable DirectWrite is to add `--disable-direct-write` when launching Atom from command prompt. However, I am not satisfied with this solution, since it does not work when I open Atom from Start Menu, Taskbar or Context menu ("Open with Atom").

**Updated question**: how do I permanently add `--disable-direct-write` argument to Atom so that it applies when launching from *Taskbar*, *Start Menu* or *Open with Atom* context menu.

Comment: Hmm, the text rendering only seems blurry on my Windows machine when I have ClearType **disabled** - and like you, setting the `-webkit-font-smoothing` option seems to do nothing on Windows.

Comment: Also, if you're comfortable hacking the source code and recompiling, you should be able to [modify the `atom/src/browser/atom-window.coffee` file](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/src/browser/atom-window.coffee) by changing the `direct-write` option to `false`.  This is set in the `AtomWindow` class, so it *may* be possible to change with scripting as well (investigating that now).

Comment: Nice! Hope you come up with something simple and effective. Because a new Atom version is announced every few days and if the compiling is a complex process it probably won't be convenient. Make sure to write an answer in order to get the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue with a custom post-update script, which fixes Registry entries and Start Menu shortcuts in order to add the `--disable-direct-write` argument.

**Shortcuts**

As I have stated at @codeSwift4Life's answer, appending `--disable-direct-write` won't work with shortcuts to the `Update.exe` process (which is actually a [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/) program). However, I *did* found out how to append arguments to the `--processStart atom.exe` command. See [this](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/367) issue.

Therefore, If you wish to change the Atom shortcut to append `--disable-direct-write`, you have to change it from:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\atom\Update.exe --processStart atom.exe
```

to one of the following lines:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\atom\Update.exe --processStart atom.exe -a "--disable-direct-write"
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\atom\Update.exe --processStart atom.exe --process-start-args "--disable-direct-write"
```

**Context menu**

To change the "Open with Atom" context menu, you have to update a few registry entries. Change them from:

```
X:\Path\to\atom\app-1.0.xx\atom.exe "%V"
```

to:

```
X:\Path\to\atom\app-1.0.xx\atom.exe "%V" --disable-direct-write
```

**Automated post-update script**

But since there are many registry entries and since you have to repeat *everything* after every update (and updates are very frequent), manual changes aren't feasible.

Therefore I have created an automated post-update script, which updates everything automatically. You just have to run it after every Atom update.

The base of my post-update script was [this coffee script](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/src/browser/squirrel-update.coffee), which is actually the stock script that overrides all our manual changes.

You have to change the aforementioned script in the following manner:

Change:

```
createShortcuts = (callback) ->
  spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName], callback)
```

to:

```
createShortcuts = (callback) ->
  spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName, '--process-start-args', '--disable-direct-write'], callback)
```

Change:

```
  installMenu = (keyPath, arg, callback) ->
    args = [keyPath, '/ve', '/d', 'Open with Atom']
    addToRegistry args, ->
      args = [keyPath, '/v', 'Icon', '/d', process.execPath]
      addToRegistry args, ->
        args = ["#{keyPath}\\command", '/ve', '/d', "#{process.execPath} \"#{arg}\""]
        addToRegistry(args, callback)
```

to:

```
  installMenu = (keyPath, arg, callback) ->
    args = [keyPath, '/ve', '/d', 'Open with Atom']
    addToRegistry args, ->
      args = [keyPath, '/v', 'Icon', '/d', atomExe]
      addToRegistry args, ->
        args = ["#{keyPath}\\command", '/ve', '/d', "#{atomExe} \"#{arg}\" --disable-direct-write"]
        addToRegistry(args, callback)
```

The `atomExe` variable is defined as following (put it at the top, but after the `require` lines):

```
# Get the latest version of atom.exe
parentDir = fs.listSync('..').filter (x) -> x.indexOf('app-') > -1;
[..., atomDir] = parentDir
atomExe = path.join(path.resolve(atomDir), 'atom.exe')
```

Also, you have to find/replace `process.execPath` with `atomExe`. This is needed because the script will be run directly via Node, and the `process` variable points to Node instead of Atom.

Finally, add the following lines to the end of the script, in order to execute shortcuts and registry updates:

```
# Update shortcuts, install context menu
updateShortcuts ->
  installContextMenu ->
```

The script is executed with `coffee squirrel-update.coffee`. You should place it into a new subfolder inside the `AppData\Local\atom` folder. You will also need `fs-plus` and `coffee-script` node packages in order to successfully run the script.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable hacking the Atom source code, you can manually disable direct-write by modifying the following file in the source tree: [`atom/src/browser/atom-window.coffee`](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/src/browser/atom-window.coffee)

Specifically, on lines 29-31:

```
  'web-preferences':
    'direct-write': true
    'subpixel-font-scaling': false
```

I don't believe the `direct-write` option is exposed to the scripting API yet, so you would have to modify & recompile Atom manually.  I would also try the `subpixel-font-scaling` option, which also might help to increase text rendering clarity.

Comment: I have found a better solution. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Open in File Browser. `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc` Then right click on Atom, choose properties. Then under target, add `--disable-direct-write` at the end. Make sure you replace `your-username` with your home folder's name. Also, make sure that if there are other shortcuts, you fix them.

[image: Properties]

Comment: Have you even tried your solution out? Because it doesn't work. This was the first thing I have done before even writing the update and setting the bounty. And also (if it worked) this is only the solution for launching Atom from Start Menu. My primary goal is to fix the "Open with Atom" context menu, which you must update in Registry - but it changes after every Atom update.

Comment: A temporary work around would be navigating to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Atom\command` and adding `--disable-direct-write` to the end